# Reflection | Emit | Dynamic Resource Generation - Added resource values using IResourceWriter.AddResource(key,value) cannot read

Tags: c#, reflection, reflection.emit, resourcemanager, assemblybuilder

I am trying to generate an assembly file with some resources. I am using `System.Reflection.Emit.ModuleBuilder` to define resources. `AssemblyBuilder` save assembly without giving any errors but when I am trying read resources, `ResourceManager` doesn't have any entry in it's `ResourceSets`. I am not sure `AssemblyBuilder` doesn't save added resources or my resource reading code has issues.

Assembly generation code:

```
public void GenerateAsm()
    {
        string myAsmName = "MyAssembly.resources";
        string myAsmFileName = myAsmName + ".dll";
        string resourceName = "MyAssembly.Resource.fr.resources";

        AppDomain appDomain = Thread.GetDomain();
        AssemblyName asmName = new AssemblyName();
        asmName.Name = myAsmName;
        AssemblyBuilder myAsmBuilder = appDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(asmName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);

        ModuleBuilder myModuleBuilder = myAsmBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(myAsmFileName,myAsmFileName);
        IResourceWriter rw = myModuleBuilder.DefineResource(resourceName, "My Description", ResourceAttributes.Public);

        rw.AddResource("ResKey1", "Resource value 1.");
        rw.AddResource("ResKey2", "Resource value 2.");
        myAsmBuilder.Save(myAsmFileName);    
    }
```

Resource reading code:

```
public void ReadResource()
    {
        ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("MyAssembly.Resource.fr.resources", Assembly.LoadFrom("MyAssembly.resources.dll"));
        string greeting = rm.GetString("ResKey1");
    }
```

Resource manager can load resource but it doesn't have any key value pairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generated assembly contains the resource values:

[image]

So the problem in a [`ResourceManager`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

> The ResourceManager class retrieves resources from a **binary .resources
>   file** that is embedded in an assembly or from a standalone .resources
>   file

And resources you are creating is not embeded binary .resources files

Try `ResourceReader`, that fits better to your situation

```
using (var reader = new ResourceReader(asm.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName)))
{
    foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in reader)
    {

    }
}
```

[image]